# How to serialize into JSON with references to objects instead of duplicating the data?

Tags: java, json, jackson

If I have this class:

```
class Person {

    int id;
    String name;
    String displayName;
    int age;

    // getters and setter, constructors, equals, hashcode, toString...
}
```

and I pass the same objects to both `name` and `displayName`

```
String name = "abcdefg";
Person person = new Person(1, name, name, 54);
```

When I serialize to JSON I will get

```
{"id":1,"name":"abcdefg","displayName":"abcdefg","age":54}
```

Which loses the reference data. I would like something like

```
{"id":1,"name":"abcdefg","displayName":name,"age":54}
```

to indicate that they are the same.

How can I do that (preferably with Jackson)?

Comment: You cannot have an output like `{"id":1,"name":"abcdefg","displayName":name,"age":54}` because it is no valid JSON.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle i said "something like", this is not the real output I want, it just indicates what I want the result to behave like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put simply, you can not. You can serialize objects, but not their references. However, if you so intend to achieve this, you can put a special character followed by a parameter name and when reading the json, you follow these steps:

1. Check if the value starts with the special character, e.g. $ (So value of displayName could be $name)
2. If yes, the rest of the value is actually the variable whose value you want to duplicate into your variable (in this case, the variable named 'name')
3. Using reflection, you get value of the referenced variable and store its value in your current variable. (at runtime, copy the value of name into displayName)

However, I would strongly suggest against it.

**EDIT** In response to the posed question 'how do people deal with increased size of JSON'

The same way people handle databases. Instead of holding objects, they assign ids to different objects and refer to the id instead of serializing a whole object into another.

For example, you have player, inventory and and item classes. Player owns inventory. Inventory can have n items. So when serializing player's inventory, you'd assign id to each item and in the inventory, you would simply put ids of items.

And yes, depending on the requirement, size of JSON could get really big.

Comment: So how do people deal with increased size of JSON. Suppose my fields weren't strings but complex objects. The size of the JSON would double.

Comment: The same way people handle databases. Instead of holding objects, they assign ids to different objects and refer to the id instead of serializing a whole object into another. 
For example, you have player, inventory and and item classes. Player owns inventory. Inventory can have n items. So when serializing player's inventory, you'd assign id to each item and in the inventory, you would simply put ids of items.
And yes, depending on the requirement, size of JSON could get really big.

Comment: I feel like this comment is the best answer. Can you turn it into one?

Answer (score 0):

Given you have some REST-services exposed, if the size of the JSON is your concern you can opt to use a HATEOAS-based approach. Instead of bundling all complex objects in the initial response, you simply add the links to these objects so you can fetch them afterwards; e.g.

```
{
    "price": 400,
    "description": "Chromebook device",
    "name": "Chromebook",
    "_links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/products/1"
        },
        {
            "rel": "product.manufacturer",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/manufacturers/18"
        }
    ]
}
```

What happens here is that instead of marshalling the manufacturer immediately, you provide a way to fetch when required.